# I have some values from doing for looping and I want to change the remainder value to string

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, modulo

Here's my code

```
for num in range(1,11): 
    print(num)
    if num % 3 == 0:
       print("hello") 
    else:
        pass
```

So I want to change every multiplication of 3 with "hello" how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Before printing the number, you must check if it is a multiple of 3. If so, print "hello", otherwise print the number.

```py
for num in range(1,11): 
    if num % 3 == 0:
       print("hello") 
    else:
        print(num)
```

Output:

```
1
2
hello
4
5
hello
7
8
hello
10
```

Comment: Hello it really works thank you, but I don't really understand what is happening with the else statement and why it didn't work in the if statement

Comment: The problem in your code is that you print the number, before checking if it is a multiple of 3. You first wrote ```print(num)``` instead of checking if num is a multiple of 3.

Comment: So that's what I have been missing, thank you very much Elidor00 I appreciate your help!